In texture painting mode, when selecting a color in the eyedropper, the value returns to the previous one after one brush stroke
Blender 4.2. In texture drawing mode, when selecting a color with the eyedropper (shift+X), the color returns to the previous value after one click of the brush. This is done in a terribly unintuitive way. I can't figure out the logic behind fixing the color in the eyedropper. It only works correctly one time out of ten.

Hello, the shortcut is now supposed to be Shift X

Hi! This is a very annoying mistake when composing the question. I meant shift + x. This is the combination that does not work. shift + s - turns on and off the long stroke option.
I have corrected my question, thank you for your answer which pointed out my mistake in composing the question

press Shift X when the cursor is over the color you want, then release the keys (don't left click anywhere), then left click to paint, it works fine for me. Maybe you are left clicking while Shift X, don't

I do everything exactly as you wrote. Unfortunately, it works exactly 1 time in 10-20 cases. As if it were a stuck key on the keyboard, although except for this case in Blender, there is no other similar problem on the computer (I am talking about a hypothetical stuck key).

The automatic translation confused me a bit. After several attempts I realized my mistake. I don't need to tap on the color like in Photoshop and other similar programs. After the shift + X command you just need to hold the pipette over the desired area of ​​color. Blender reads the value simply by the cursor coordinates. Thank you for your participation in my problem. All the best to you.

Yes that's what I said, don't left click   ;)

The automatic translation confused me a little. This slightly alleviates the magnitude of my shame. 8)))
The question can be closed, thank you very much!

@MrGravicaper Questions here don't get closed when they got an answer, if an answer solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the tick mark next to it so it turns green. This indicates others stumbling across this question that there is a solution to it.

press ShiftX when the cursor is over the color you want, then release the keys, don't left click while you press the keys.
